Object.hasOwnProperty vs optional chaining vs in keyword
Let's say I have an object in JavaScript like this
{
    Name: 'Prem',
    ClassGroup: {
        Id: 123,
        Name: 'English Class'
    },
    isActive: true
}

Suppose now I have an array of objects, with the structure above, but only some of the objects in the array would now have the ClassGroup property. Note: For my use case, if ClassGroup property exist, Id is guaranteed. But, in general, what is the difference between these 3 when checking for a property in JavaScript object?
let arrayOfObjects = [{}, {}, {}, {}];
let setOfUniqueIds = new Set();

arrayOfObjects.forEach(item => {
    // what is the difference between the 3
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('ClassGroup')){
        //add id to setOfUniqueIds
    }
    //vs
    if ('ClassGroup' in item) {
        //add id to setOfUniqueIds
    }
    //vs
    if (item.ClassGroup?.Id) {
        //add id to setOfUniqueIds
    }
})

What is the difference between these 3: Object.hasOwnProperty vs optional chaining (?.) vs 'in' keyword, are they all just a preference of readability?
I have tried all these 3 methods, all of them return the same values. I would like to know, what is the main difference between these 3 approaches.
